# Image Comparision using SURF

Tags: image-processing, surf

**Problem:**

I have a "face" images database of multiple persons, in which for each person I have multiple images(each have something different in it in terms of facial expression like smiling, thinking, simple etc).

While **testing**, I am having a testing data set of "smiling face image" of persons for whom image already exist in database but images in database and test data set are not exactly same (i.e. two images of same person smiling at different time, out of which one is in database and other is in test data set).

Now, the problem is my application **detects the person correctly but in facial expressions it mis-matches** ex.: in place of "smiling face" sometimes it gives "simple face".

**PS:** Efficiency in terms of finding exact person is **100%** but facial expression mis-match is a problem.

**Algo I am using:**

1. Image Normalization and enhancement
2. SURF Feature Detection and matching

Can anyone suggest what may have gone wrong or what can be a better algorithm/approach to solve this problem ?

**Is there a better algorithm than SURF for comparing two images??**

Answer (score 0):

I would use other face recognition algorithms, for example: LBP + svm.

You can use face-rec.org to read about face recognition algorithms, or the results page of the "labeled face in the wild" page:
http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/results.html

If your'e using OpenCV, you can check out OpenCV's module for face recognition
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/

Comment: Yes, I am using opencv.